# How to receive files via Bluetooth

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I'm running Ubuntu 16, and if I pair my computer with my Android phone via bluetooth, and send a file to my computer, Ubuntu shows a prompt "Incoming file XXXXXXXX, Accept/Reject?" If I accept it, it appears to download fine, and says the file went into my `~/Downloads` folder, and even provides a link. However, that folder remains empty. Even searching for the exact filename it says was transferred finds nothing on my computer. Where are these files going?

Answer (score 2):

I too had trouble finding the received file. I changed the settings so that all received files should be stored in a specific directory (e.g. `~/Downloads/Bluetooth Incoming`"). Ubuntu will prompt to accept/reject the incoming file. After I click on the accept button it shows the progress on the Bluetooth Manager that it is receiving the file but it does not store the received file on the specified directory. It turns out it stores the received files in `~/.cache/obexd/` directory